# Is Regex Coach broken when it comes to m/ multi-line?

Tags: regex

Is Regex Coach broken when it comes to "treat string as multiple line" ?

(There is another option and "treat string as single line" for 's',  I think that's badly named and probably means "dot matches new line". I've seen perl use `/s` as a modifier.  And a test in regex coach shows that 's' is "dot match new line".

It has two boxes.  M and S

[image]

described here

[image]

The description sounds strange because they are opposites and you'd only need one checkbox to perform a boolean option. Also you can choose both. "single line" and "multi line".

As mentioned, no doubt 's' is "dot matches new line". So is not an opposite to 'm'.

And 'm' is I suppose "read the whole lot" / potentially match the whole lot, as a text editor with regex support would. I know perl has a -0777 option for that.

But look at this

[image]

I have not picked multi-line option there.

So surely the regex shouldn't be able to work across lines

This certainly is different to how perl operates.

Perl without -0777 is "line by line" mode, and (while unlike sed, it can find a new line character), it (like sed), can't span across lines.

(commands done in cygwin as it provides a nice echo - an echo with -e, and it provides perl too)

```
$ echo -e 'abc\ndef' | perl -pe 's/abc\n//'
def

$ echo -e 'abc\ndef' | perl -pe 's/ab[^z]*//'
def
```

I have read https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html   that multi-line mode affects what caret and dollar match. And I guess m-(multi-line) still spans new lines and doesn't just affect caret and dollar.

For example in perl

```
$ echo -e 'abc\ndef\nghi' | perl -0777 -pe 's/abc\ndef//'

ghi
```

Yet see what Regex Coach does

The regex can span across lines..And ^ matches the beginning of the multi-line string,  $ matches the end of the multi-line string. Yet multi-line is not checked

[image]

---

If I turn multi-line on, I get the same result for that string and that regex

[image]

---

And in this example, when I tick the multi-line box, it acts rather like single line in the sense that caret and dollar are matching beginning and end of line. Though we know it's not single line because from above examples, \n spans across lines.

[image]

--
And with multi-line unticked it acts a bit like multi-line in that caret and dollar aren't matching line by line.. they must be matching beginning and end of string, and it doesn't match anything

[image]

I know that Regex Buddy is better. But I like how regex coach has the common single letter modifiers which is a good reminder to me to be familiar with those.

But is the operation of 'm' in regex coach completely broken?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a case of badly named option,
the "treat string as multiple line" for /m affects "^" and "$",
while the "treat string as single line" for /s affects ".".

As for your tests cases with \n, they aren't representive, perl -pe do one test per line in a loop, with regex coach you're testing a regex against a single string (except if /s), which isn't the same at all.

By the way, I disagree with your "I know that Regex Buddy is better.". I'm still using this tool just for the "step" tab that allow me to see the execution of the regex step by step, which is very usefull to find out why it matches or not a specific string, or why the execution of the regex is slow. I haven't been able to find that feature in any other tool, software or web.